# Como faco download de um diretorio em FTP via php?

Tags: php, ftp

Bom eu consegui fazer download de um arquivo especifico do meu FTP via php , mais eu preciso baixar um diretorio inteiro alguem sabe como faco isso, ja achei exemplo no PHP manual mais nada!

meu codigo para baixar um arquivo especifico

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = 'teste.pdf';
$server_file = './teste/teste1.pdf';
$ftp_server="ftp.exemplo.com";
$ftp_user_name="usuariopedro";
$ftp_porta="22";
$ftp_user_pass="senhapedro";

$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_porta);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: tome cuidado com endereços, nomes de usuário e senha.

Comment: sim, sao exemplo

Comment: Adicionei à resposta um exemplo de como poderia ser feita a listagem dos arquivos e download dos arquivos.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo protocolo FTP, não há a possibilidade de fazer o download de um diretório. Embora essa opção exista em muitos programas, ela e gerida pela própria aplicação. Isso é feito listando-se os arquivos do diretório e o download um a um.

Segue exemplo de como poderia ser feito em PHP

```php
// define some variables
$ftp_server="ftp.exemplo.com";
$ftp_user_name="usuariopedro";
$ftp_porta="22";
$ftp_user_pass="senhapedro";
$directory = ".";

$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_porta);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $directory);

foreach ($files as $file) { 
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
        continue; 

    ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY)
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```